# An object with property values of null is received when Jquery.post is used

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

After switchng to ASP.NET MVC I'd never needed to send a JSON object to controller action, so I was comfortably using jqeury.post for my AJAX calls. All of the action methods were just receiving primitive  types. But recently I had to send a JSON object, so I did this:

```
$.post(myUrl,JSON.stringify({param1:myJsonObject}),success(data){...},'json');
```

When I put a breakpoint to the beginning of the action method, to my surprise, I find all the properties of the received object to be null. However, if I don't "JSON.stringify" the object before sending, I can get the string properties correctly, but those with DateTime type are always 01.01.0001..

Now, if I try, so to say, old fashion way, everything goes just fine:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({param1:myJsonObject}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           //any code
        }
    });
```

All the properties are set to correct values. I've looked at the source code of the jquery.post and realized that the contentType was not set, so I set it to be application/json. But that didn't help either. The jquery version is 1.8.2. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({param1:myJsonObject})` should look like `{ param1: JSON.stringify(myObject) }`

Comment: How are you sending the `DateTime` values. If its `01/01/0001` on the server, then it suggest the value you are sending in not valid, therefore not binding so and its the default (`DateTime.Min`) value

Comment: No, if I debug it in Chrome script debugger, I can see that the date is a valid date. Besides that, I've also tested to send that date separately and there was no such problem. So if that date is inside an object, it's not correct but if it's a separate parameter, then it's fine.

Comment: @johan, I tried it, that doesn't help. Besides that, I do the same thing with the $.ajax version and works just fine

Comment: If your posting back a javascript object representing your model( eg. `{id: 1, name: 'Mike', BirthDate: '1/1/1970' }` then it just needs to be `$.post(myUrl, myJsonObject)` if the action method accepts the model as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, but somehow the date is always 01/01/0001. Again, if I pass exactly the same date separately, then I get the correct passed date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$.post(myUrl,JSON.stringify({param1:myJsonObject})).success(function(data){

 },'json');
```

Comment: I do just that. Can't see any difference between what you suggest and what I've posted in my question.

Comment: And I think you have some typos there. Or am I wrong? Especially this part `JSON.stringify({param1:myJsonObject})).success`. There's extra ")" and you put "." instead of ","

Comment: you have missed success with in "function" success(function(data){

 },'json');

Comment: Huh, now I see, so it's not a typo. :)